# What does "at the 1-1's" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

"The fact is I'm doing pretty good at the 1-1's for now".

The sentence is from "Unforgettable S02E08"
http://www.allreadable.com/97bcHhDk

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Earlier, someone says "Listen, if you wanna move on up, and pay a fortune to live in some hole in the wall in the 1-0-0's It's fine by me. 1-1's will get along just groovy without you."

He is referring to the fact that in (expensive, high-class) Manhattan, all the zip-codes (the postal codes) [begin with 100-](http://map-world.us/manhattannew-york-zip-code-map.html), whereas in (working-class, earthy) Brooklyn, they all [begin with 11-](http://map-world.us/brooklyn-zip-code-map.html).